# Unable to commit to an empty git repo

Tags: git, git-bash

I have created an empty Git repository in Atlassian Stash and cloned it.

```
$ git clone http://me@myrepo/my/repo.git
...
warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.
```

Then I've created some files, added them via `git add` and wanted to commit via `git commit`. I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Unable to determine active branch in current context !
ERROR: GITLib::Branch::get_current died at line 41
```

When I do `git rev-parse HEAD` I get:

```
$ git rev-parse HEAD
HEAD
fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
```

**When I issue `git branch -a` to see if there are any remote branches, the output is empty.**

Let's create a branch locally:

```
$ git checkout -b "foo"
Switched to a new branch 'foo'

$ git commit -m "test"
ERROR: Unable to determine active branch in current context !
ERROR: GITLib::Branch::get_current died at line 41
```

How do I get my repo in a workable state?

I tried issuing `git commit --allow-empty`, `git init` but it didn't change anything.

**Edit:**

When I just create an empty repo locally with `git init`, then `git add` and try to `git commit` similar happens:

```
ERROR: GIT::Command::git_or_die died at line 164
```

**Edit 2:**

It seems an internal issue due to a hook in my company. I'll follow up with details if this gets resolved.

Using Git Bash 1.8.5.2 @ Win7.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Warning: You appear to have cloned empty repository in TortoiseGit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8130894/warning-you-appear-to-have-cloned-empty-repository-in-tortoisegit)

Comment: @l0b0 I *do* expect this repo to be empty. But from I've read all over the net, if I cloned an empty repo, I should be able to create commits in it, but here clearly it is not the case.

Comment: Yes, but did you `git add` any files before committing, as mentioned in the dupe? There might be a special case about the first commit not being empty.

Comment: Yes I did. Either when trying an empty commit with `--allow-empty`, or when adding things via `git add` before and then committing normally, the same issue happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused indeed by global hooks installed by the platform team in my company. The message looks like it was some Git internals and that's why it mislead me.

What I've done was to remove the hooks locally from `.git/hooks` and deactivate the hooks copying on the repo creation:

Run `git config --system -e` to open the editor for system config file (`C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\etc\gitconfig` in my case) and removed the following lines:

```
[init]
    templatedir = D:/tools/Git/hooks/templates
```

Answer (score 3):

Rather than cloning the empty repository from Stash, try creating a new repository locally (in a new directory) with:

```
git init .
```

Add your files and make your first commit. The freshly init'd repository should have a proper `HEAD` and `master` branch:

```
git add file1.txt
git add file2.txt
git commit
```

Then, add your empty Stash repo as a remote and push master there:

```
git remote add origin http://me@myrepo/my/repo.git
git push -u origin master
```

Comment: When I created an empty repo locally with `git init`, now I get `ERROR: GIT::Command::git_or_die died at line 164` when trying to commit. Hmm I guess it could be related with the global hooks inside the company, need to investigate it further.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you guessed it right, this is something totally into your (and actually our, as I'm in charge of them) company hooks.

The error:

> ERROR: Unable to determine active branch in current context !
>      ERROR: GITLib::Branch::get_current died at line 41

occurs when we try to find the name of the current branch. 
Currently we are using "git branch --list" to find it, **but in case of empty repo this returns an empty result**.

The solution would need to go to something else, probably "get symbolic-ref" as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2111099
(issue is we have to support clients still in Git 1.7.9)

Phil.