# Git clone: "You appear to have cloned an empty repository"

Tags: git, git-clone

Some colleagues and I have been working on a project stored in a private Git repository. Historically, there have been no problems, but recently I attempted to clone and got the following problem:

```
Cloning into 'project'...
warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.
Checking connectivity... done.
```

A `git log` provides:

```
fatal: your current branch 'master' does not have any commits yet
```

This isn't correct - my colleague pushed plenty of non-empty changes on Dec. 6 (although now that branch isn't showing on a `--single-branch` clone attempt). After ssh-ing into the Git repository, there is plenty of files and folders there.

So, my questions:

1. How could this have happened?
2. How can we recover the repository?  It seems the stuff is on the remote repo, but for some reason, it isn't aware that it's there.

Comment: Did they push to a branch that isn't `master`? If so, do you just need to check out that branch?

Comment: You either cloned the wrong repository or they're lying to you (computers can't lie -yet-).

Comment: They pushed to a branch that isn't master, but as I mentioned, we are unable to check out that branch (or any other branch).

I doubt he's lying :-)

Comment: This question is very similar to [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8130894/warning-you-appear-to-have-cloned-empty-repository-in-tortoisegit) but the answers on the old question were not really helping.

Answer (score 10):

**If the repo is hosted on a gitlab server**, and you used git over `http` to clone the repo, it could be related to this:

[Git over HTTP will receive an empty repo if `giltab-git-http-server` is not properly configured](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/2727)

> If for some reason `gitlab-git-http-server` is not properly configured,
>   or you are using a custom nginx or Apache proxy that forwards directly
>   to Unicorn and you attempt to clone via HTTP, the request succeeds,
>   you receive a 200 and an empty repo.

A **quick fix** is to use ***git over ssh*** to clone the repo.

Answer (score 5):

You have cloned the correct repository. I think they have not pushed into the master branch. The other branches will be there like origin/development-example.
You need to make a local branch which can track the remote branches and then you can get the latest code. This is how you can track remote branches:

```
git branch --track dev-example origin/dev-example
git checkout dev-example
```

Comment: There was a master previously.  It has recently disappeared, and we don't know why.  We are unable to track any other branches, because the remote isn't reporting that they're there.  For instance:

git branch --track symbolicPorts origin/symbolicPorts
error: the requested upstream branch 'origin/symbolicPorts' does not exist
hint: 
hint: If you are planning on basing your work on an upstream
hint: branch that already exists at the remote, you may need to
hint: run "git fetch" to retrieve it.
hint: 
hint: If you are planning to push out a new local branch that...

Comment: check git fetch origin

Comment: Interestingly, that hung for a couple of seconds and then returned with no verbal output.  It seems like it might have done something, but following that with a "git pull" returns: "Your configuration specifies to merge with the ref 'refs/heads/master'
from the remote, but no such ref was fetched."

Comment: check git branch -r. This will tell you how many branches were fetched. If you find some new branches like origin/something then track those branches the way i told you in my answer.

Comment: git branch -r is blank.

Answer (score 3):

This happens when you are cloning a freshly created repository with no commits.

As it says, it is just a warning. If it is expected that there is nothing in the repository, you can go ahead and add files and commit and push back.

If it is not supposed to be empty, contact the person/admin who gave you the link.

Comment: Thank you for this answer! Really bad from git, that new users are always presented with a warning on their very first action.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was a silly mistake when I've tried to clone a repo from another machine: I've used `https` instead of `ssh` as protocol in the URL. Surprisingly I've got no error, but the message “You appear to have cloned an empty repository”.

Comment: This question has long been irrelevant to me - we eventually pushed a local backup repository.  But this is far and away the most plausible cause that I've heard so far.  I wonder if it has something to do with configuration?

Answer (score 0):

A colleague of mine just had a similar issue. Frankly, I have no idea why it happened, since a simple HTTPS cloning worked for the rest of our team. But, ultimately, here's a solution that helped - instead of `git clone` we had to do basically the same, but manually:

1. Create an empty folder for your project, say `project/`
2. In `project/`, run `git init`
3. Add the remote: `git remote add origin https://github.com/yourAccount/yourrepo.git`
4. Pull from the remote: `git pull origin master`

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue after migrating to a new Gitlab server.

It has been fixed after performing the steps below.

For example, if the project Git URL is `http://gitlab.abc.work/neptune-open/neptune-developer-guide.git`

1. Clone the repo

   ```
   git clone git@gitlab.abc.work/neptune-open/neptune-developer-guide.git
   ```
2. Edit the local Git config (for example, with `vi`):

   ```
   vi neptune-developer-guide/.git/config
   ```

   Then change the "origin" url to http format:

   ```
   [remote "origin"]
       url = http://gitlab.abc.work/neptune-open/neptune-developer-guide.git
   ```
3. Modify any file in the project
4. Commit the modifications to the file

   ```
   cd neptune-developer-guide && git add . && git commit -m "fix git clone issue"
   ```
5. Push it

   ```
   git push origin master
   ```

Comment: Instead of manually editing the `.git/config` file, you can (you should) use `git remote set-url` (https://stackoverflow.com/q/2432764/2745495, https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote#Documentation/git-remote.txt-emset-urlem)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue that turned out to be a from a race condition:

```bash
gh repo create xxx --template template-name
gh repo clone xxx
```

This resulted in cloning of empty repositories.

By adding a delay (I did 15 seconds but I'm sure a much smaller interval would work)

```bash
gh repo create xxx --template template-name
sleep 15
gh repo clone xxx
```

Comment: To anyone reading this answer, `gh` is the Github CLI: https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_repo. If you are not using Github, simply replace the `gh` commands with your platform-specific CLI or maybe just with plain `git` commands. The _important_ part of this answer is the `sleep`/delay part in between creating the repo and cloning it.